# Getting rid of strings in data file

Tags: c, scanf

I have written a code that reads a square matrix from a .dat file and a vector from a separate .dat file and augments the two and does gauss jordan elimination to get the augmented matrix into row-reduced-echelon form. I am trying now to make it user friendly and crash elegantly when the user input is nonsensical. For instance, I have a check to make sure the matrix is square and that the length of the vector matches the dimension of the matrix. What I am trying to do now is to check if there are any characters or symbols in the data files that are not numbers.

My attempt: something like `scanf("%lf",  )` would work in that it stops when it comes across one of these symbols. The problem is that my input is not from command line. (command line is not really an option here because I want the code to be able to accept a huge matrix that the user would not want to sit there and enter in command line). Doing `fscanf("%f",  )` goes nuts when it encounters a string.
Is there anything like scanf that will just stop but not go crazy when it encounters a letter, etc?
If not, are there any other suggestions?

Comment: read everything as string, test validity and convert...

Comment: Don't make it crash at all! Any sane program will perform error checking and just quit with an error if it cannot operate properly. As for your question, it's probably cleanest to separate parsing, validation and processing, and so you can just quit if there's a parsing or validation error.

Comment: +1 for "*... crash elegantly ...*" :-) Anyhow to be serious, I fully agree to what Kerrek SB did write above! Additionaly I'd like to mention `scanf()` returns `EOF` after "*having gone crazy*", so you could easyly catch this condition during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fgets` to get a line into a preallocated buffer, then `strtoX` to extract a floating-point number. ( `X` = `f` for `float`, `X` = `d` for `double`, `X` = `ld` for `long double`.
Its signature is `X_t strtoX(const char *nptr, char **endptr)`, where `X_t` is the corresponding type (`float`, `double`, or `long double`).

Until the end of line is reached (`**endptr = '\n'`), increment the line pointer (which is set to point to the preallocated buffer, and if it doesn't increment after `strtoX`, then increment it until is does.
Use two variables, like so:

```
char *lp = buf;
char *lp2 = buf;
do {
    X_t x = strtoX(lp, &lp2);
    if (lp == lp2 && *lp != '\n') {
        ++lp;
        continue;
     }
     if (*lp2 == '\n')
         goto read_line;
      // do something with x
 } while (1);
```

My code isn't great, but it should show the point.

Also, `strtoX` for `X` = `f` and `X` = `ld` isn't supported until C99 / POSIX 2011.